# Define a List that is Always Resumed

Tags: lists, enumitem

I have a list that I need to behave as if it is *always* resumed. With the `enumitem` package, I know I can use `series=<name>` on the *first* list, and use `resume*=<name>` on *subsequent* lists.

However, my issue is that I have these lists defined in macros and the macros don't know which one will be first (so that it can specify the `series=<name>` option) and which will be the subsequent ones (which need a `resume*=<name>`).  Furthermore, any item (including the first one) may be repeated, so if any one item is assumed to be the first one, then the count gets reset.

How can I define al its that always continues numbering independent of the order?

[image]

### Notes:

- A *hack* solution would be to pass in the `series=` and `resume*` option when the macros are invoked, but I'd prefer not to have to do that.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList]{label={\arabic*)}}

\newcommand*{\ListA}{%
    \begin{MyList}[series=ResumedList]
        \item Item A
    \end{MyList}
}

\newcommand*{\ListB}{%
    \begin{MyList}[resume*=ResumedList]
        \item Item B
    \end{MyList}
}


\begin{document}
    \ListA
    \ListB
    
    \ListB
    \ListA
    
    Number of list items = \arabic{MyListi}
    
    \ifnum\arabic{MyListi}=4\relax
        \textbf{PASS}: Correct count
    \else
        \textbf{FAIL}: Incorrect count. Count should be 4.
    \fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Follow-up question: [Always resumed list does not always resume if invoked from within an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366179/4301).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are there several series? Because if not, this works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList]{
  label=(\arabic*),
  resume
}

\newcommand*{\ListA}{%
    \begin{MyList}
        \item Item A
    \end{MyList}
}

\newcommand*{\ListB}{%
    \begin{MyList}
        \item Item B
    \end{MyList}
}


\begin{document}
    \ListA
    \ListB

    \ListB
    \ListA

    Number of list items = \arabic{MyListi}

    \ifnum\arabic{MyListi}=4\relax
        \textbf{PASS}: Correct count
    \else
        \textbf{FAIL}: Incorrect count. Count should be 4.
    \fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: You beat me to this very answer (in particular, the use of the `resume` option in `\setlist`) by a few seconds. :-) However, I would write `\ifnum\value{MyListi}=4` instead of `\ifnum\arabic{MyListi}=4\relax`.

Comment: @Mico any idea on the case where there might be several series? I'm guessing testing for the existence of the series and then adjusting options accordingly

Comment: I have a different list for different series, so this works great for me.  Thanks.