# Always resumed list does not always resume if invoked from within an environment

Tags: lists, enumitem

`MyList` is an always resumed `enumitem` list:

```
\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList,1]{label={\arabic*.}, resume}% ALWAYS resumed
```

but seems to break if the *first* use of `MyList` is from within another environment (orange text).  In the MWE, this environemnt adds a color to the list and then envokes `\begin{MyList}`:

```
\newenvironment{MyColoredList}[2][]{%
    \color{#2}%
    \begin{MyList}[#1]
}{%
    \end{MyList}%
}%
```

But, the same environment used *after* the direct use of `MyList` seems fine (blue text):

[image]

### Notes:

- The second level is not resumed and there is no issue with it. Thus I removed the code that was testing that part.
- My question is not how to color a list, but how to have it `resume` numbering when it is invoked from within an environment.

## References:

- [Define a List that is Always Resumed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298269/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList,1]{label={\arabic*.}, resume}% ALWAYS resumed
\setlist[MyList,2]{label={\alph*)}}%           NOT resumed

\newenvironment{MyColoredList}[2][]{%
    \color{#2}%
    \begin{MyList}[#1]
}{%
    \end{MyList}%
}%


\begin{document}
    \begin{MyColoredList}{red}
        \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{orange}% <--- This should be number 2
        \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}% <--- This should be number 3
        \item Second Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}
        \item Third Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{blue}
        \item Fourth Item (this works!!)
    \end{MyColoredList}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `resume` option is local only, for global resume (i.e. settings that survive groups) you should the `resume*` option or even the `series` key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it the hard way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList,1]{
  label=\arabic*.,
  before=\setcounter{MyListi}{\value{MyList}},
  after=\setcounter{MyList}{\value{MyListi}},
}% ALWAYS resumed
\setlist[MyList,2]{label=\alph*)}%           NOT resumed

\newcounter{MyList}
\newenvironment{MyColoredList}[2][]{%
    \color{#2}\begin{MyList}[#1]
}{%
    \end{MyList}%
}%


\begin{document}
    \begin{MyColoredList}{red}
        \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{orange}% <--- This should be number 2
        \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}% <--- This should be number 3
        \item Second Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}
        \item Third Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{blue}
        \item Fourth Item (this works!!)
    \end{MyColoredList}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `resume` option is always local, i.e. only within the current group. Using a list within some environment and trying to resume the list in another environment later on will fail in the sense that the information is lost.

The remedy is `resume*`, which must be specified locally, however and can't be given as option to the `\setlist` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}



\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList,1]{label={\arabic*.},resume}% ALWAYS resumed
\setlist[MyList,2]{label={\alph*)}}%           NOT resumed

\newenvironment{MyColoredList}[2][]{%
  \color{#2}%
  \MyList[#1]
  }{%
  \endMyList%
}%


\begin{document}
    \begin{MyColoredList}{red}
        \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}[resume*]{orange}% <--- This should be number 2
    \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}% <--- This should be number 3
        \item Second Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}
        \item Third Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{blue}
        \item Fourth Item (this works!!)
          \begin{MyList}[resume*]
            \item Inner Item
            \end{MyList}
    \end{MyColoredList}
    \begin{MyColoredList}{violet}
        \item Fifth Item (this works!!)
          \begin{MyList}[resume*]
            \item Inner Item
            \end{MyList}
    \end{MyColoredList}

\end{document}
```

A better way can be achieved with the `series=` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList,1]{label={\arabic*.},resume=foo}% ALWAYS resumed
\setlist[MyList,2]{label={\alph*)}}%           NOT resumed

\newenvironment{MyColoredList}[2][]{%
  \color{#2}%
  \begin{MyList}[#1]
  }{%
  \end{MyList}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyColoredList}[series=foo]{red}
\item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{orange}% <--- This should be number 2
    \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}%  <--- This should be number 3
        \item Second Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}
        \item Third Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{blue}
        \item Fourth Item (this works!!)
          \begin{MyList}[resume*]
            \item Inner Item
            \end{MyList}
    \end{MyColoredList}
    \begin{MyColoredList}{violet}
        \item Fifth Item (this works!!)
          \begin{MyList}[resume*]
            \item Inner Item
            \end{MyList}
    \end{MyColoredList}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution. Unfortunately that won't work for me as I don't the order the list items will come in. I need it to auto resume.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Hm, I don't understand. There's only one `resume` in the  `\setlist` part right now (apart from the forced resume on the last two inner lists). It does auto resume. You can change the series and the resume later on, if needed

Comment: But I don't know upfront which is the first list item to start the series with. The list `\begin{MyList} \item .. \end{MyList}` are stored and output later. These elements can also be other text, not just list elements, so at the output stage I don't know what is being output. Similar to `\def\MacroA{\begin{MyList} \item .. \end{MyList}}`, `\def\MacroB{\begin{MyList} \item .. \end{MyList}}`, `\def\MacroC{Some text with perhaps lists in it, or not}`. And then these three can be output in _any_ order: `\MacroA\MacroB\MacroC` or `\MacroC\MacroA\MacroB\MacroA`, etc.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I have no clue for this (yet) ...

Comment: Based on your solution I was attempting to use `environ` to save the environment `\BODY` and do some `\aftergroup` (so that list would not be in a group) but can't seem to get that to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newlist{MyList}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[MyList,1]{label={\arabic*.},
        after={\xdef\enit@resume@MyList{\noexpand\c@MyListi=\the\c@MyListi}},resume}% ALWAYS resumed
\setlist[MyList,2]{label={\alph*)}}%           NOT resumed

\makeatother
\newenvironment{MyColoredList}[2][]{%
    \color{#2}%
    \begin{MyList}[#1]
}{%
    \end{MyList}%
}%

\begin{document}

    \begin{MyColoredList}{red}
        \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{orange}% <--- This should be number 2
        \item First Item
    \end{MyColoredList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}% <--- This should be number 3
        \item Second Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyList}
        \item Third Item
    \end{MyList}
    Some text
    \begin{MyColoredList}{blue}
        \item Fourth Item (this works!!)
    \end{MyColoredList}
\end{document}
```

[image]