# enumitem, is possible to put "series=<name>" in \setlist?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I define own list, for example `mylist`. For some reason I like to name it with `series`, for example as `series=ML` for resuming purposes: `resume=ML`. Adding this locally, for example as in the following MWE, this works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[mylist,2]{nosep, leftmargin=*, label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth} % simulate new environment 
                                 % where I like incorporate mylist with
                                 % \mylist ... \endmylist
\begin{mylist}[series=ML, resume=ML]
   \item    example A
   \begin{mylist}
       \item    sub example A1
       \item    sub example A2
    \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}
    \end{minipage}

    \bigskip
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{mylist}[series=ML, resume=ML]
   \item    example B
   \begin{mylist}
       \item    sub example B1
       \item    sub example B2
    \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I move `series=ML, resume=ML` from option of `mylist` to `\setlist` like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*.,
                   series=ML, resume=ML  % <---
                   }
\setlist[mylist,2]{nosep, leftmargin=*, label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{mylist}
   \item    example A
   \begin{mylist}
       \item    sub example A1
       \item    sub example A2
    \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}
    \end{minipage}

    \bigskip
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{mylist}
   \item    example B
   \begin{mylist}
       \item    sub example B1
       \item    sub example B2
    \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

it trow the error:

```
! Package enumitem Error: Misplaced key 'series'.
```

Interestingly, if I after than forced compilation, I get desired result.

In `enumitem` documentation (I use version 3.9 from 2019/06/20) is nowhere described that `series` in `\setlist` is not allowed, but all examples of its use are as it is shown in the first MWE.

Do anyone know, how to convinced `enumitem` that will work in second MWE without error?

**Edit:**
After correcting errors in my MWE (added missed `\begin{minipage}` and `\end{minipage`) accidental I discover that removing `series` from list definition in the second example gives desired result:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist,1]{resume=ML  % <---
                   leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*, after=\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}
                   }
\setlist[mylist,2]{nosep, leftmargin=*, label=(\alph*)}
```

Comment: To me this looks more like a feature request to the package author than a question for this site.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat , you may be right. I wasn't sure if I was doing anything wrong. At the same time, I hoped that anyone here knew of a solution. I wanted to write to the author, but the "http://www.texnia.com/enumitem.html" page didn't seem active for a long time.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for an always resumed list? If so, then perhaps [Define a List that is Always Resumed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298269/4301) is a duplicate of this.

Comment: @PeterGrill, thank you very much for the link. I will test this solution ASAP in my target application: defining new environments containing `mylist` activated by `\mylist` and terminated with `\endmylist`. On the first sight I don't see, that the question is duplicate, but I will see after my test. (hopefuly done today)

Comment: If you type `h` at the error prompt, then it will tell you `'series' and 'resume*' must be used in the optional argument of lists`, and there is a specific macro to test this condition in the code, so it's definitely not supported, for some (probably good) reason. I couldn't find out what it is, though, sorry. Perhaps ask for the author's view on this: https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/issues

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, you ae right! I didn't check this before, however in the package documentation are examples, where `resume` is used in `\setlist`, see *8.2 Restarting enumerates, page 19* : `\setlist[enumerate]{resume}`.  I report my wish to package author on http://www.texnia.com/contact.html. Now I will look on github.

Comment: @Zarko That's `resume`, which (I think) is allowed, different from `resume*`. And indeed, the documentation points you to texnia.com, so that's probably the right address.

Comment: @Zarko: Sorry, I wasn't clear. [Define a List that is Always Resumed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298269/4301) is not an exact duplicate of the question asked here, but I thought perhaps that was what you were trying to achive.

Comment: @PeterGrill, it is intriguing. I will make test late evening (GMT), when all disturbance around me will go to sleep :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill, I test proposed solutions on your questions. Unfortunately I didn't succeed to adopt any of them to my needs (use `\mylist` ... `\endmylist` in definition of the new environment).

Comment: @Zarko: What is your the actual result that you want to be able to achive? With the resutls at the link I provided and the follow-up question, you define a list type that you want always resumed and then you don't need to specify it to be `resumed` when you use it.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding `\setlist[mylist]{resume}` at the initial declaration works fine.  Series is not necessary here.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist]{resume}% <=================
\setlist[mylist,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[mylist,2]{nosep, leftmargin=*, label=(\alph*)}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{mylist}
        \item    example A
        \begin{mylist}
            \item    sub example A1
            \item    sub example A2
        \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
\lipsum[1-2][1-3]
    \begin{mylist}
        \item    example B
            \begin{mylist}
                \item    sub example B1
                \item    sub example B2
            \end{mylist} 
        \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \begin{mylist}
            \item    sub example B1
            \item    sub example B2
        \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see in addendum to my question, I already discover this. Now I wonder, why I didn't close a question after this :-(, probably I decided then to wait if some new (better) solution will appear. Anyway, thank you very much again and +1 for the your answer!